# Как сделать, чтобы после выбора пункта из Spinner появлялся новый Spinner (которого изначально не было)

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Например: в первом списке мы выбираем страну, появляется новый (ниже первого), там выбираем город, появляется новый и т.д пока не дойдем до конечного значения, который не вызывает новый список.

```
public class SelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    Spinner spinnerBase = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.baseSpinner);

    Spinner spinnerSecond = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);
    Spinner spinnerThird = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.thirdSpinner);
    spinnerBase.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, final int position, long selectedId){
    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if (position==1){
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this, R.array.forPress, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerSecond.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    else if (position==2){///...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте в макете нужное вам кол-во спиннеров и меняйте им видимость.

Comment: @kizoso почему вы считаете, что это не является ответом?

Comment: @Dmitry, в сообщении не достаёт конкретики как такое организовать. Не приведены даже названия свойств, и нету детальной проработки предложенного варианта.

Comment: @kizoso этот ответ есть решение на вопрос в той формулировке, в которой он представлен. Сообщение "Не является ответом на вопрос" предназначено для ответов, которые и не пытаются ответь на вопрос. Подробно здесь https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5703

Comment: убрала комментарий